# How to Clear Odoo 15 Cart

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-15

Good day,
We want to only allow one product order in Odoo Cart, although we are selling all products on our website.

We want a customer to only order one product at a time, so my question is How can I clear the cart in Odoo 15 when it is not empty every time a customer click Add to Cart.

We have thought of changing the add to cart function but we have failed please help.

```
@http.route(['shop/cart/update'], type='http', auth="public", methods=['POST'], website=True)
def cart_update(self, product_id, add_qty=1, set_qty=0, **kw):
    """This route is called when adding a product to cart (no options)."""
    sale_order = request.website.sale_get_order(force_create=True)
    if sale_order.state != 'draft':
        request.session['sale_order_id'] = None
        sale_order = request.website.sale_get_order(force_create=True)

    product_custom_attribute_values = None
    if kw.get('product_custom_attribute_values'):
        product_custom_attribute_values = json_scriptsafe.loads(kw.get('product_custom_attribute_values'))

    no_variant_attribute_values = None
    if kw.get('no_variant_attribute_values'):
        no_variant_attribute_values = json_scriptsafe.loads(kw.get('no_variant_attribute_values'))

    sale_order._cart_update(
        product_id=int(product_id),
        add_qty=add_qty,
        set_qty=set_qty,
        product_custom_attribute_values=product_custom_attribute_values,
        no_variant_attribute_values=no_variant_attribute_values
    )

    if kw.get('express'):
        return request.redirect("/checkout?express=1")

    return request.redirect("/cart")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simple always delete the order_line records from the order in the add_to_cart function.

Would be something like this :

```py
@http.route(['shop/cart/update'], type='http', auth="public", methods=['POST'], website=True)
def cart_update(self, product_id, add_qty=1, set_qty=0, **kw):
    """This route is called when adding a product to cart (no options)."""
    sale_order = request.website.sale_get_order(force_create=True)
    if sale_order.state != 'draft':
        request.session['sale_order_id'] = None
        sale_order = request.website.sale_get_order(force_create=True)
    # Delete the lines if there are some:
    if sale_order.order_line:
        sale_order.order_line.unlink()
    # ...
```

In case you have an error for unauthorized operation, you'll have to sudo() your sale_order so `sale_order.sudo().order_line.unlink()`